# Convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Number

Tags: java

I have a String object and I need to convert to java.lang.Number.

```
Number num = null;
Object cellContents = ".475";
```

If I try to cast the *cellContents* to Number directly,

```
num = (Number) cellContents;
```

it throws an exception:

```
E[java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String]:  : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
```

I searched but could not get a complete answer as to how I can achieve this.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't just cast the reference type. You're getting an exception because the String object to which it points is not a Number *object*.

You can, however, cast the reference to a String, if you know it's a String. You can convert it to a real value with `Double.valueOf( String )` or `Float.valueOf( String )`. Once you get a double, you can use [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to turn it into a Double, which isa Number.

```
Object cellContents = ".475";
Number num = null;
if ( cellContents instanceof String ) {
   try {
       double d = Double.valueOf( (String) cellContents );
       num = (Double) d; // Auto-boxing
   }
   catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
     ...
  }
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't cast a String to a `Number`, because they are not covariant (they don't fall in the same inheritance hierarchy).

You can convert the `String` to `float` or `double` using [`Float#parseFloat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Double#parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) respectively, which is what you would need in most cases.

Using [`Float#valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Double#valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) creates instances of wrapper classes.

So, depending upon what you need, you can use any of them. I'll show here the first `parseXXX` methods:

```
float strToFloat = Float.parseFloat(".475");
double strToDouble = Double.parseDouble(".475");
```

---

However, if you are dealing with monetory value, or some other value, where floating point precision is of concern, then you should use `BigDecimal` instead:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(".475");
```

Comment: Based on the values that I have seen, they are all float or double. Maybe I could suggest this!! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can not simply convert a String into Number directly as they are not in same hierarchy.But good news is Java Wrapper API do most of the task for you automatically IE, convert a valid String into Wrapper you want and throws a NumberFormatException if the passed String is not a valid Number or other Wrapper.

You should use.

```
Integer.parseInt(String) throws NumberFormatException
```

OR

```
Double.parseDouble(String) throws NumberFormatException
```

they both return Number Integer and Double respectively and both ARE-A Number.

Comment: Integer.parseInt won't work with the example provided (".475")

Comment: Because .475 is not an Integer i was generally saying you should use Integer if you have something like "474", but you case ".475" use float or Double

Comment: Double.parseDouble() returns a double - not a String or a Number.

Comment: @SachinVerma. Please edit your post to correct it. The mistakes pointed out in previous comments is still there.

Comment: Still incorrect - Double.parseDouble() returns a double -- not a Double. Autoboxing may obscure this detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
num = new BigDecimal((String)cellContents);
```

Comment: why explicit cast while we can `cellContents.toString`?

Comment: toString can do all sorts of things if the object is not a String. with the cast, you get an error if it is something else.

Comment: @Thilo, is it good to introduce BigDecimal to new Programmers when there are much basic things availble??

Comment: You mean "basic things" like floating points? Sure, if you want them to learn by pain.

Comment: Won't this convert the _cellContents_ to a BigDecimal object. What if _cellContents_ is a float or an int?

Comment: OP says cellContents is a String.

Comment: @Thilo: What I meant by the statement was that, as mentioned in the example, what if the contents are not BigDecimal, they could be just integers or decimal values. This cast would explicitly cast the contents to BigDecimal object.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should cast your object to string.

You can try something like the following code:

```
Number num = null; 
Object cellContents = ".475";
num = cellContents.toString();  
num = (Number) num;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast ".475" to Integer. However you can cast it to Float or Double using

```
float x = Float.parseFloat(".475");
```

or

```
double y  = Double.parseDouble(".475");
```

You should search more about Wrapper Classes in Java and AutoBoxing in java to get basic clear. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks!! But I was looking for a more generic approach that would simply parse the given object to a Number type. So I figured out that it is not possible!!

Comment: If you can explain me why you are doing so ? I can help solve your problem

Comment: I have a column which is being computed from 2 columns in the database. Since this is a customer database, and the columns are defined as date and float. These 2 columns are divided and the computed column is displayed.